# Problem with different versions of rutimes /sdk with visual studio 2022

Tags: linux, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, versioning

My computer has crashed so i have done a new installation of visual studio 2022.

The problem is: its not the same version.  I have done a jump from 17.1.X to 17.7.1

So before crash i developped on windows with `net/asp runtimes 6.0.1` and after i publish my application on linux

---

***Now after the reinstallation of my visual studio, my windows environment is:***

**dotnet --list-sdks**

```
2.1.202
5.0.408
6.0.412
7.0.109
7.0.400
```

**dotnet --list-runtimes**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.21
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.10

Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.10

Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.21
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.9
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.10
```

---

***On linux, my environnment is:***

```
dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.1
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1

dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.101
```

---

[List of all .net 6 versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

You could see `the version of runtime net and asp is 6.0.21 on win`, so few questions:

do i have to install the sdk 6.0.101 on windows (the same on linux) or i can use the sdk 6.0.412?

what i have to declare in my project file to continue to keep the compatibility with my Linux?

i suppose if i launch a compilation on the newest visual studio, now the runtime of application will be 6.0.21? and no possibility to deploy on the linux? (i cant upgrade the linux now)

Another question: Is there a link between the sdk version and the runtimes version?

Thanks for your help about this problem

FYI:

in my asp.net project i have:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and for a c# project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Publish</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  :
  :
</Project>
```

Comment: I believe targeting .net6 targets any 6.x run-time.  It'll use whatever's on the machine...  the run-time is determined by the machine it's run on, unless you build self-contained (run-time included)... if you build self-contained the run-time will be whatever's on the build machine... presumably the newest version of 6 run-time it can find.

Comment: Hi, do you got any exception during your programming or deployment? In my humble opinion, what we could define in the project is the .net version like what you showed, it's .net 6 or .net 7, we couldn't define 6.x.x version inside the project. so since what you have in the project is .net6 and both of your win and linux machine already installed .net 6 runtime, your application should be able to run in both machine.

Comment: @TinyWang, no problem on the dev machine. and  i read that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/   but its complex to understant

Comment: no problem is the good message. easily know like, .net 6 project requires .net 6 runtime/.net 6 SDK, no matter it's .net 6.x.x version of runtime/SDK